# Angular material - Page with md-card not showing scrollbar

Tags: angularjs-material

I am working on a web page which users Angular-material. I use md-card to show some data. The layout seems to have some problem. Even though the content in y is larger than the screen, the scrollbars do not appear. I have spent few hours changing all possible values. But no luck.
This is my toplevel controller.

```
<body ng-app="TulirWebApp" ng-cloak layout="column">
<div ng-controller="toplevelCtrl">
    <md-content style="overflow: auto">
        <div layout="row">
            <span flex></span>
            <md-button ng-click="addToCart(book)">கூடையில் சேர்க்க</md-button>
            <a href="#/cart">கூடை</a>
            <p ng-if="user.logged_in">{{user.nickname}}</p>
            <a ng-if="user.logged_in" ng-href="{{ user.logout_url }}">Logout</a>
            <a ng-if="!user.logged_in" ng-href="{{ user.login_url }}">Login</a>
        </div>
        <div flex class="md-padding" layout="row" layout-align="center center">
            <div flex-gt-md="60" flex-md="80" flex-xs="100">
                <div ng-view></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </md-content>
</div>
```

Here is the particular page, which won't show scrollbar even though the content is larger than screen.

```
<md-card>
    <md-card-header>
        <md-card-header-text>
            <span class="md-title">Cart</span>
        </md-card-header-text>
    </md-card-header>

    <md-content-card>
        <div ng-repeat="item in items" align="right">
            <strong>{{ item.book_title_ta }} (Rs. {{item.mrp}})</strong>
            <span flex></span>
            <md-input-container>
                <input aria-label="Quantity" type="number" step="any" ng-model="item.quantity" min="1"
                       max="20"/>
            </md-input-container>
            <strong> x {{ item.selling_price }} = {{ item.quantity * item.selling_price }}</strong>
            <md-button ng-click="deleteItem(item)">Delete</md-button>
            <md-divider></md-divider>
        </div>
        <div align="right">
            <strong>Total = Rs. {{ calculateTotal() }} /- </strong>
        </div>
    </md-content-card>
</md-card>
<md-card>
    <md-card-header>
        <md-card-header-text>
            <span class="md-title">Address</span>
        </md-card-header-text>
    </md-card-header>
    <md-content-card>
        <md-input-container class="md-block">
            <label>Phone</label>
            <input ng-model="address.phone" type="text" placeholder="Phone Number">
        </md-input-container>
    </md-content-card>
</md-card>
```

Any suggestion on what could have gone wrong?

Comment: You're using the wrong element. It should be `<md-card-content>`, not `<md-content-card>`. Also, please use the [tag:angularjs-material] tag.

Comment: In fact, I started with md-card-content. It also does not work.

Comment: `md-card-content` is the right element to use!